# MKMetersBetweenMapPoints incorrectly returning distance in meters

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit

running this code:

```
NSLog(@"%f", MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(MKMapPointMake(33.6523, -118.507), MKMapPointMake(34.516, -117.628)));
```

returns this:

```
0.015819
```

When the expected output should be ~136900. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're giving a regular latitude and longitude to `MKMapPointMake()`. An `MKMapPoint` contains and `x` and `y` value, not latitude and longitude.

Use `MKMapPointForCoordinate(myLocation)` to convert your locations to map points, then give those to your `MKMetersBetweenMapPoints()` function.

Or easier still, use [`-distanceFromLocation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a) with two `CLLocation` objects. It gives you back a distance in meters, taking into account the curvature of the earth.